# GROUP BY Subquery returns more than one row

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I'm looking for a way to solve the following situation. I have a table that I need to return only one number for each "`p.pays`", This query is supposed to list "`nom` from table `Pays`" where at least half of the "`athlete`" have are in the table "`Resultat`" but my subquery returns more than one line is there a way I can match "`p.code`" in both the query and the subquery so it only returns 1 line per "`p.code`".

```
SELECT p.nom , count(*) FROM Athlete a
INNER JOIN Pays p ON a.pays = p.code
GROUP BY p.code HAVING count(*)/2 >= (SELECT count(*) FROM Athlete a
                    INNER JOIN Pays p ON a.pays = p.code
                    INNER JOIN Resultat r ON a.code = r.athlete
                    GROUP BY p.code);
```

Expected result, show Countries"Pays" where at least half of the athletes "Athlete" have won a medal (Athlete is in the `Resultat` table). :

```
  p.nom    | count(*)
|----------|--------|
|Albania   | 134    | <-- Total Number of athletes "Athlete" in the 
|Argentina | 203    |                    country "Pays".
| ...      | ...    |
```

Comment: Could you post a sample of your two tables?

Comment: As per the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), help us help you and edit your question to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to have two counts of athlethes in the country:

- all athletes
- the resultat athletes

Use a conditional count for this:

```
SELECT p.nom, count(*)
FROM pays p
INNER JOIN athlete a ON a.pays = p.code
GROUP BY p.code
HAVING COUNT(*) / 2 >= 
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE a.code IN (SELECT athlete FROM resultat))
ORDER BY p.nom;
```